# RadAsyncUpload doesn't render when using jquery .load()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a fairly simple web user control written in c# that places a telerik RadAsyncUpload control on the page.
It's in a web user control because I wanted to fiddle with the save filenames in a consistant manner across my site and output some standard html around it.

I then place my web user control on a simple web form and then load this page into a div using jquery .load() method.

When I run the page in a browser window by itself, everything renders fine:

```
http://localhost/subPage.aspx   ---  All good, the RadAsyncUpload renders along with everything that is supposed to be there.
```

if I use the following code in my MainPage.aspx:

```
$('#mydiv').load('subPage.aspx')
```

I get only the submit button being rendered in the html.  Actually I get the following part of the rad control too, but not all of it:

```
<div id="rauUploads2" class="RadAsyncUpload RadUpload RadUpload_Default">
  <!-- 2011.3.1115.40 -->
  <input id="rauUploads2_ClientState" name="rauUploads2_ClientState" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Am I asking too much??  am I not able to do what I thought I could..??

Do I need to use a lightbox or something to display my subPage.aspx???

Thanks

Comment: almost 5 questions in one...do you want us to do a project?

Comment: I'm sorry if you read 5 questions.. I've put as much detail in as I thought would help for someone to hopefully answer the question and didn't ask once for code so no I don't want you to do a project.
It boils down to "has anyone tried to use the RadAsyncUpload (telerik) control on a page loaded into a div using the jQuery .load() function"..
Is that more succinct for you Arun?